# Apply Excel table formatting style without converting a range to a table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a range I want to be formatted as a table, similar to what is seen in the `Format as Table` dropdown, but without the range being changed into a table:

[image]

To do this, one can follow [this procedure](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/apply-a-table-style-without-inserting-an-excel-table-65331c5e-995c-4203-bd87-7b4ea0949d85%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20).

However, when one of these styles is applied, and the range is converted to a table, any formulas in the table header row are converted to static text. I do not want this to happen because I have formulas I wish to keep in my header row.

How can I apply table formatting quickly, without have to copy/paste my headers (so they aren't destroyed), convert the table back into a normal range, and re-paste the original headers?

Comment: You can go to Design- Tool- Convert to Range, it will not remove the format in the range.

Comment: @Lee I'm aware of that. The problem is, if I use the `Format as Table` tool to apply the table formatting, it removes the formulas from the headers.